# Vaadin excel export with converter values

Tags: vaadin, export-to-excel, vaadin7

I'm trying to export an Excel corresponding to a FilterTable using [Vaadin TableExport](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/tableexport). That Filtertable has some columns storing Dates and other class type elements, so I'm using `setConverter` function to print them as specific Strings:

```
filerTable.setConverter("dateColumn", dateConverter);
filerTable.setConverter("myClassColumn", myClassConverter);
```

**dateConverter** and **myClassConverter** are instances of some classes to print that column values as Strings.

The problem comes when I want to export the table as an Excel: That `setConverter` conversions are not being applied to the output file. For example, date cells are being exported as string ('42741,0080787037' instead of '06/01/17 0:11'). The code section to export the Excel file is:

```
ExcelExport exp = new ExcelExport(new CustomTableHolder(filerTable), "excel.xls");
exp.setRowHeaders(true);
exp.export();
```

Is there any way to export the table exactly as shown, having applied `setConverter` function?

Comment: AFAIK, vaadin doesn't have a built-in support for excel export. Are you using addons for that (e.g. [TableExport](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/tableexport)). If so, please, include a link to addon.

Comment: Yes, I'm using that addon. I added it to the post.

Comment: Haven't you look on Vaadin Spreadsheet? I heard it can solve your problem.

Comment: No, I don't. My tables are so simple and I only need to download excel files, so I think that TableExport addon should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [add-on sources](https://github.com/jnash67/tableexport-for-vaadin), it seems that this feature is supported but 2 things have to happen in order for it to work:

- you have to use a [`PropertyFormatTable`](https://github.com/jnash67/tableexport-for-vaadin/blob/master/tableexport/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/tableexport/PropertyFormatTable.java) (nothing fancy, just a wrapper over table for this custom purpose)
- set the [`setUseTableFormatPropertyValue(true)`](https://github.com/jnash67/tableexport-for-vaadin/blob/master/tableexport/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/tableexport/ExcelExport.java#L628) on the `ExcelExport`

**Code:**

```
public class ExcelExportTableComponent extends VerticalLayout {

    public ExcelExportTableComponent() {
        // basic table configuration
        Table table = new PropertyFormatTable();
        BeanItemContainer<Person> itemContainer = new BeanItemContainer<>(Person.class);
        table.setContainerDataSource(itemContainer);
        table.setConverter("age", new AgeConverter());

        // add some dummy data to the table
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            itemContainer.addItem(new Person("Name " + i, "Surname " + i, random.nextInt(99) + 1));
        }

        // add components to the layout
        addComponent(table);
        addComponent(new Button("Export to excel", event -> {
            ExcelExport excelExport = new ExcelExport(table);
            excelExport.setUseTableFormatPropertyValue(true);
            excelExport.excludeCollapsedColumns();
            excelExport.setReportTitle("Demo Report");
            excelExport.export();
        }));
    }


    // basic bean for data binding
    public static class Person {
        private String name;
        private String surname;
        private int age;

        public Person(String name, String surname, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }

        public void setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }

    // custom converter
    private static class AgeConverter implements Converter<String, Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer convertToModel(String value, Class<? extends Integer> targetType, Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
            return Integer.valueOf(value.substring(0, value.indexOf(" years")));
        }

        @Override
        public String convertToPresentation(Integer value, Class<? extends String> targetType, Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
            return String.valueOf(value) + " years";
        }

        @Override
        public Class<Integer> getModelType() {
            return Integer.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<String> getPresentationType() {
            return String.class;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]